# useInfiniteQuery not being able to update nextPageParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I've been using React-Query v3 for my project, and I faced a problem with `useInfiniteQuery`.

FeedListSearch.js

```js
  let FeedListSearchQuery = useInfiniteQuery(
    "tagSearch",
    () => apiClient.feedTagSearch({tags: props.tags }),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
        return pages.length + 1;
      },
    },
  );
```

apiClient.js

```js
  feedTagSearch: async ({ pageParam, tags }) => {
    let url = `/feed/search?pageNumber=${pageParam}`;
    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      url = url + `&tags=${tags[i]}`;
    }
    return await instance
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(url)
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Feed Search Failed" + error);
      });
  },
```

while the first page of the infinite query returns result just fine (pageParam=0), it has not been able to update the nextPageParam as intended. Hence when I calls for the next page, it keeps adding the old result of pageParam=0 (also kept requesting old URL in apiClient as well). How can I update the nextpageparam correctly, and get further pages' response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems:

1. `tags` should be part of the query key (somewhat unrelated, but still important)
2. `pageParam` is passed to the `queryFn`, but you ignore it:

```
let FeedListSearchQuery = useInfiniteQuery(
  ["tagSearch", props.tags],
  ({ pageParam = 0 }) => apiClient.feedTagSearch({tags: props.tags, pageParam }),
  {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
      return pages.length + 1;
    },
  },
);
```

`pageParam` is also undefined on the first render, so I've set the default value to zero.

Comment: Gotta love when the library creator answers your question!

Comment: too much credit here . I maintain the lib but didn't create it